# Must I save the captured image to the Camera Roll when using UIImagePickerController with source type camera?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

From the docs of UIImagePickerController:

> When the user taps a button to pick a newly-captured or saved image or
>   movie, or cancels the operation, dismiss the image picker using your
>   delegate object. For newly-captured media, your delegate can then save
>   it to the Camera Roll on the device. For previously-saved media, your
>   delegate can then use the image data according to the purpose of your
>   app.

So this reads like I **MUST** save the captured image to the Camera Roll. Is this true? Reason for rejection if not done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need to save to Camera roll when UIImagePickerController is dismissed. I have done this in several apps.

Comment: This is correct, and to add to this, when you register as the delegate of UIImagePickerController it will pass you the UIImage that was obtained. So you are responsible for doing what it is you want to do with it, whether that is saving it to the camera roll or to your app's Document directory for use within the app.